# Keras multiclass training accuracy does not improve and no loss is reported

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am not sure what is wrong with either my data or the way I have framed the problem.
I have framed a time series dataset with multiple input features on x (10 features) and y is framed as one hot encoded multiclass output with features in the shape of (61726,3). The y class has three potential values with estimates of frequency of each :

- [1 0 0], 4200
- [0 1 0], 2000
- [0 0 1], 2100

My model in Keras is such as below:

```
    trainy = to_categorical(trainy)
    testy = to_categorical(testy)
    
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=trainx.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    #Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  # optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001),
                  optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    trainy_ints=numpy.argmax(trainy, axis=1)
    class_weights=class_weight.compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced',
                                                    classes=numpy.unique(trainy_ints), 
                                         classification           y=trainy_ints)
    class_weights=dict(enumerate(class_weights))
    print('\tusing class_weights: ',class_weights)
    model.fit(x=trainx,y=trainy,
              batch_size=batchSize,epochs=epochs,
              class_weight=class_weights)
```

As suggested in other answers, I've tried changing the optimization function to SGD and changing the learning rate, but that did not help .

I discovered another answer about inbalanced classes, and thought that this makes sense for my problem since the algorithm is likely always predicting the most-frequent class, so I also tried using class_weights parameter as you can see, but I still get the same problem.

This is an example my problematic output during training. You can also see that the first epoch always seems to start with lower accuracy and then at the second epoch it always maxes out.

```
Epoch 1/100
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.4818   
Epoch 2/100
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.4933
Epoch 3/100
63/63 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan - categorical_accuracy: 0.4933
```

Any insight greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had 'nan' still in my input dataset, which was throwing off the training process.